# O que devo fazer para fazer upload de arquivo com símbolos de depuração no flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bundle, google-play

Estou publicando um app feito com Flutter e estou recebendo uma mensagem de aviso da PlayStore dizendo o seguinte:

"Este App Bundle contém código nativo, e você não fez upload dos símbolos de depuração. Recomendamos que você faça upload de um arquivo de símbolo para facilitar a análise e a depuração de falhas e ANRs."

Eu criei o arquivo AppBundle com a assinatura e não recebi nenhuma mensagem de erro no processo de upar o app pra loja, mas recebi essa mensagem de aviso e estou sem saber o que devo fazer para arrumar

este é meu arquivo Build.gradle

Eu vi algo sobre ter um arquivo que seria referenciado no build.gradle, mas não entendi muito bem

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ifmgsje.ifmap"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName 'Version 1.0.0+1'
    }

       signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}
```

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Veja a documentação de suporte do Google [Desofuscar ou simbolizar stack traces de falhas](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=pt-BR#zippy=%2Cc%C3%B3digo-nativo-gerar-um-arquivo-de-s%C3%ADmbolos-de-depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2Cfazer-upload-de-arquivos-usando-o-play-console%2Cfazer-upload-de-arquivos-com-a-api-google-play-developer)

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se vc ainda tá com esse aviso aparecendo... é q eu passei pelo mesmo problema, mas depois de várias tentativas frustradas consegui resolver assim:

- Instalei o NDK: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk
- No arquivo `android/app/build.gradle` adicionei o NDK à sessão defaultConfig `defaultConfig { ... ndk { debugSymbolLevel } }`
- E por último, fiz o upload do arquivo de símbolos: Esse vídeo aqui mostra o passo a passo como fazer https://youtu.be/wiEZZ-30CbM.

Comment: Links a recursos externos são bem-vindos, mas lembre-se de fornecer um contexto para cada link, para que seus colegas usuários possam ter uma ideia do que se trata e por que está aqui. Sempre destaque a parte mais relevante de um link importante, caso o site de destino esteja inacessível ou fique permanentemente off-line.